# how i can make outside clickable div in vanila javascript

Tags: javascript, freemarker

I have javascript code that uses in freemarker , the problem is I do not know how i can make the outside div click works .

first line it comes from freemarker where I pass ids ( we are in a list so I will get more than one element and function for every item you see in the code )

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>
> idNum ='${event.occurenceId}';
>
> // Get modal element and set  display to none
> var modal = document.getElementById(idNum).getElementsByClassName('modal')[0];
>
> // Get the open modal button
> var modalBtn = document.getElementById(idNum).getElementsByClassName('modalBtn')[0];
>
> // Get close button 
> var closeBtn = document.getElementById(idNum).getElementsByClassName('closeBtn')[0];
>
> myData.push({id:idNum, modalElement:modal, modalButton:modalBtn, closeButton:closeBtn,openModalFun:openModal,closeModalFun:closeModal,outsideClickFun:outsideClick});
> var ite = myData.find( ({id}) => id === idNum);
>
> function openModal(){
>        myData.find( ({id}) => id === this.parentNode.id).modalElement.style.display='block';
> }
>
>
> //function to close modal
> function closeModal(){
>     myData.find( ({id}) => id === this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id).modalElement.style.display='none';
> }
>
> //function to close outside click
> function outsideClick(e){
>     if(e.target == ite.modalElement){
>         ite.modalElement.style.display='none';
>     }
> }
>
> // Listen for open click 
> ite.modalButton.addEventListener('click', ite.openModalFun);
>
> // Listen for close click 
> ite.closeButton.addEventListener('click', ite.closeModalFun);
>
> // Listen for outside click 
> window.addEventListener('click',ite.outsideClickFun);
>
> </script>
> ```

Comment: You mean if the user clicked anywhere on the body except for the modal? Sometimes people puts a mask behind the modal and the entire screen is covered by the mask(translucent or not), if that is your case, you can also bind the click on the mask

Comment: yes, exactly that what i meant I want to be able to click anywhere except the modal and the modal closes , I read about the bind but to be honest I did not understand how i can use it in my code , i tried it but did  not succeed

Comment: Can you clarify the issue in your question(you can edit it), it sounds like you don't know how to bind click event, from your comment.

Answer (score 1):

So If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is have a popup div where if a user clicks outside of the popup div, the popu div closes/disappears but if they click anywhere inside of it, it does nothing.

What you want to do here is have to divs let's call this `modal`and `modalContent`

Now the `modal` is your div that takes the whole screen. you have to set it to `100%` for both height and width whatever you do, make it cover the whole screen.

Now `modalContent` is your actual popup with information. give this a css `z-index` of maybe `1` so it comes in front of everything else.

Now in your JS, set that when `modal` is clicked, `modal` and `modalContent` hide.

Pretty much it.

Here is a very simple working example to assist you;

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal

Comment: This is basically the modal mask approach Ali, it's safer since the modal mask disappears after the modal is closed.

Comment: Thanks Hungism, and mw509 
I managed to do that :)

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please mark it as an answer